# Why is my autoclicker not working?

Tags: mouse, mouse-click

I recently built a 125 cps autoclicker (using a 555 timer circuit and some mouse-breaking), since the normal polling rate of a mouse is 125 hz.
For some reason, my computer is only detecting 35 to 40 cps. I don't know why.

Comment: Ive voted to close this - you have not provided sufficient details on how you buit this autoclicker (Indeed I'd be surprised if 1% of the people here know what a 555 is), which leads me to my second reason - I dont believe that "building your own hardware" is in scope here.

Comment: @davidgo, I respectfully disagree -- the 555 timer Is a classic part, and many, if not most, electronics hobbyists know about them and have used them. That said, this could *also* be asked in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ . [Perhaps I should take a survey: how many Superusers know what a 555, CK722, IN34 or 6V6 is? ;-) ]

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I absolutely agree that the 555 is a classic part - but I only know about it because I dabbled in engineering 30 years ago - I don't think most people on superuser are electronics hobbyists, but I do agree it would be interesting to find out.   I would bet there is a loose correlation between the likelyhood of knowing what a 555 is, the age of the user and also their reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the electronics in the mouse can work that fast. Microswitches are actually pretty noisy (due to the contact "bouncing") so the electronics might have a debounce filter in it that limits the time between clicks for them to be considered valid clicks.

You could probably get a faster click rate in software using something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or AutoIt which can send mouse clicks outside of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the 555 timer is not *synchronized* with the polling interval, causing "artifacts", similar to that from an A-to-D converter, where the sampling rate is not at least a few times higher than the signal frequency.

From [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analog-to-digital-conversion/): "According to the Nyquist theorem, the sampling rate must be at least 2 times the highest frequency contained in the signal." See also [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Analog_and_Digital_Conversion/Nyquist_Sampling_Rate) for more on the *Nyquist Sampling Rate*.